# how to make snackbar appear above popupwindow?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow, android-snackbar

snackbar not working inside popupwindow. Here is the code what i have tried.
first i created popupwindow

```
    //popupwindow
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) AddMembersToEventActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View editFamilyPopupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit_family_member_popup,null);
    final RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)editFamilyPopupView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    final PopupWindow editFamilyPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            editFamilyPopupView,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    ....
```

calling snakcbar method

```
    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.rashi_msg),parentLayout);
    ...
```

showing snackbar

```
    //show snackbar
public void showSnackBar(String message,ViewGroup viewGroup){
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(viewGroup, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

    snackbar.show();
}
    //...
    //exception
    02-20 13:52:20.747 20762-20762/divine.calcify.com.divine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process:
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:188)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:220)
                                                                           at divine.calcify.activities.AddMembersToEventActivity.showSnackBar(AddMembersToEventActivity.java:866)
                                                                           at divine.calcify.activities.AddMembersToEventActivity$9.onClick(AddMembersToEventActivity.java:663)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

how to make snackbar appear above popupwindow?

Comment: From where are you calling `showSnackBar`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that exception because Snackbar couldn't attach to a `view`.

More in details what's really happening is that `Snackbar` is calling [**getContext()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) on `viewGroup` which seems to be `null` and causes the exception to be raised.

p.s. Note that link points to `View.getContext()` but that's okay as `ViewGroup` inherits from `View`.